# Mapped drive inaccessible after router reboot

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, networking, mappeddrive, unc

I have a server with a mapped drive on it (maps to a directory on another server across the network).

I also have an application that writes a file to the mapped drive (regularly scheduled, but monitored by e-mail).

Periodically a router in between the first server and the second server gets rebooted (either due to maintenance or as part of a weekly reboot schedule - it gets rebooted whether it needs it or not).

If I have an Explorer window open and connected to the mapped drive during this reboot, the mapped drive becomes inaccessible. If I don't everything carries on tickety-bo.

Why? And is there something I can do about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably because the TCP connection was broken after the router reboot, so the SMB connection that underlies the mapped drive needs to be reestablished.

If the router is rebooted on a regular schedule, you could always create a scheduled task on the first server that runs a simple batch file which deletes and then reestablishes the drive mapping after the reboot...

Answer (score 0):

There's no way for the scheduled task to copy to the share if the network connection goes down (ie- your only route to the remote server goes away).  The data isn't going to get there with no route.  Are you sure the scheduled task is running during one of these reboot times?

Comment: Yup. We're 3 or 4 hours afterwards. I can ping both machines from any other machine, even open up a share on both of them. But until I close and re-open that explorer window (or point it at another drive), the first server is unable to see networked drive.